# Relationship between the eigenvalues of a complex matrix and the eigenvalues of its skew-hermitian part

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose, $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is a non-hermitian matrix and it is decomposed as $A = \dfrac{1}{2}[A + A^{\star}] + \dfrac{1}{2}[A - A^{\star}]$. Now if $\lambda_{i}[A-A^{\star}] = -j b \; \forall i$, where $b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, then can it be guaranteed that the imaginary part of $\lambda_{i}[A] < 0$ for $i=1,2 \cdots n$ ? For example $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
  -0.4878 - j0.3902 & -0.2439 - j0.1951 \\
  -0.2439 - j0.1951 & -0.4878 - j0.3902
\end{array} \right]$ for which $\lambda_{i}[A-A^{\star}] = \{-j0.3902, \; -j 1.1707\}$.

Comment: Is spectral theorem useful in this regard? Please suggest any relevant references.

Comment: Can you define $j[A - A^*]$? What is this?

Comment: This means that the eigenvalues of the skew-hermitian part of A matrix are all negative.

Comment: What is $A$ doing there then?

Comment: A is any complex matrix; neither hermitian, nor symmetric.

Comment: You are not understanding me. You said $\lambda_j[A - A^*]$ stood for e-values of the skew-hermitian matrix part of $A$ (I don't even know what this means if you assumed $A$ to be non-Hermitian in the first place). $A- A^*$ is the difference, not $A$.

Comment: I am trying to relate the eigenvalues of A matrix if it is given that the eigenvalues of the skew-hermitian part of A are all negative. Because eigenvalues of a matrix are not the sum of eigenvalues of its hermitian part and the skew-hermitian part.

Comment: What you state and what you are writing are different things. You keep talking about eigenvalues of the skew-Hermitian part when you keep writing $\lambda_i[A - A^*]$.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get your point. But, I tried to mean eigenvalues of the skew-hermitian part of a complex matrix. If the matrix is already hermitian, as you are saying, then its skew-hermitian part would have been zero.

Comment: No, I have considered them as purely negative-imaginary.

Comment: Bhowrnick What on earth is purely negative-imaginary? The field $\mathbb{C}$ has no order.

Comment: That means eigenvalues are imaginary with negative numerical value. for example -j1, -j100 etc.

Comment: What you have written, it implies the eigenvectors of a matrix and the eigenvectors of its skew-hermitian part are the same. But it is not true always. How lambda and mu can be taken together?

Comment: Sorry you are correct $v_j$ may not necessarily be an e-vector of $A^*$.